# keytool Java and TLS/SSL

Tags: java, ssl, sslsocketfactory

I have a socket client and server socket. The server has a keystore with a key in it.

```
keytool -genkey -alias mystuff -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks -keysize 2048
```

This page says that it generates a key pair when the above command is run. https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html

When I run this command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks
```

I can see:

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: mystuff
Creation date: 25-Jun-2015
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Richard, OU=OSS, O=OSS, L=Yat, ST=Hamp, C=GB
Issuer: CN=Richard, OU=OSS, O=OSS, L=Yat, ST=Hamp, C=GB
Serial number: 48ee5103
Valid from: Thu Jun 25 17:09:18 BST 2015 until: Sun Jun 19 17:09:18 BST 2016
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  60:63:F2:41:A3:AB:DB:E0:63:F9:B0:E4:C8:2C:90:D4
     SHA1: 52:8A:F7:76:82:B7:E9:BE:D3:4E:4A:3C:DD:CF:8A:58:A6:9F:70:DE
     SHA256: 3C:80:C1:0E:E7:30:DD:69:9F:97:A9:02:F9:4E:6E:57:84:82:C5:22:0E:7F:7A:EE:C1:D2:7A:8A:45:A3:86:79
     Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
     Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 42 4F 07 15 3A 9A 8C 59   6A 65 EB B6 62 FD 77 C5  BO..:..Yje..b.w.
0010: AC E3 B2 4F                                        ...O
]
]
```

What I am seeing there is the certificate but what does the entrytype: PrivateKeyEntry mean ?

So ... when I load the Java Server:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=somepassword EchoServer
```

I can point it to the keystore so it can be used in setting up the SSLServerSocket.

Now on the client side does the client just need the exported crt from that key store using this command ?

```
keytool -export -alias mystuff -file mystuff.crt -keystore keystore.jks
```

Or is something else required to enable secure SSL between the Java Sockets.

**Additional Information**
Standard Java Notes
Running server and client using SSL

http://stilius.net/java/java_ssl.php

First copy certificate file that you created before into working directory and run server with these parameters (notice that you have to change keyStore name and/or trustStrorePassword if you specified different options creating certificate:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=mySrvKeystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=123456 EchoServer
```

And now again copy certificate file that you created before into working directory and run client with these parameters (notice that you have to change keyStore name and/or trustStrorePassword if you specified different options creating certificate:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=mySrvKeystore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=123456 EchoClient
```

If you want SSL debug information just add these parameters when running server and/or client:

```
-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol -Djavax.net.debug=ssl
```

**javax.net.ssl.keyStore-** Location of the Java keystore file containing an application process's own certificate and private key. On Windows, the specified pathname must use forward slashes, /, in place of backslashes.

**javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword -** Password to access the private key from the keystore file specified by javax.net.ssl.keyStore. This password is used twice: To unlock the keystore file (store password), and To decrypt the private key stored in the keystore (key password).

**javax.net.ssl.trustStore -** Location of the Java keystore file containing the collection of CA certificates trusted by this application process (trust store). On Windows, the specified pathname must use forward slashes, /, in place of backslashes, .

```
If a trust store location is not specified using this property, the SunJSSE implementation searches for and uses a keystore file in the following locations (in order):

    $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/jssecacerts
    $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts
```

**javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword -** Password to unlock the keystore file (store password) specified by javax.net.ssl.trustStore.

**javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType -** (Optional) For Java keystore file format, this property has the value jks (or JKS). You do not normally specify this property, because its default value is already jks.

**javax.net.debug -** To switch on logging for the SSL/TLS layer, set this property to ssl.

Richard